# disable new line after /form in IE

Tags: html

I have a form in IE where it starts a new line after /form. Is there any fix to this?

Answer (score 2):

I found if I used `style="display: inline;"`, the line disappeared. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try a CSS reset file
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Or try to add this to the page

```
form {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
```

**Edit**

I noticed the newline disappeared when adding a doctype to the document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
</html>
```

Comment: That would work, but IE is picking up that it should start a new line for a /form